# How to multiply a given number by 2 without using arithmetic operators in c?

Tags: c

How to multiply a given number by 2 without using arithmetic operators in c language?

Answer (score 19):

Use bit wise << operator:

```
x = x << 1;
```

This works for integer and long numbers (not floating point numbers).

It basically shifts the binary contents one position to the left, which is equivalent to multiplying by 2

Comment: Read about binary in your own language. 2 is "10" in binary, and three is "11". So in binary, 3 * 2 = 6 is written like this: 11 * 10 = 110 WHICH IS THE SAME AS A LEFT SHIFT.

Comment: "and long numbers" -- what?  Isn't the long data type an integer one?

Comment: Actually you are right. I mean it works for int and long data types, which are all integers.

Answer (score 7):

Left shift.

[But why would you want to do that](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?PrematureOptimization)? Leave that kind of optimization to the compiler.

List of operators and plenty of examples on [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operators_in_C_and_C%2B%2B).

Comment: That tag was added after my answer, but even for homework it would be a good idea to point out that this is not the proper way to do multiplication in a high level language.

Answer (score 6):

Just to extend on kgiannakakis post:

The shift operator `<<` works because it shifts at the binary level - effectively in base 2. Just as moving a number by one place to the left in decimal (base 10) is the same as multiplying by 10. For example:

```
23 (move to left one digit) = 230 = 23 * 10
```

For the example (using the prefix 0b to represent binary numbers):

```
    3 * 2 = 6
0b11 << 1 = 0b110
```

Shifting by other numbers is equivalent to multiplying by 2 'n' times, or multiplying by 2 to the nth power (2^n)

```
   3 * 8 =    3 * 2^3    = 24
0b11 * 8 =   0b11 << 3   = 0b11000 (note the trailing zeros)
```

And an example in decimal to finish it off:

```
23 (move to left 3 places) = 23 * 1000 = 23 * 10^3 = 23000
```

Answer (score 5):

**Caution:** Shifting might not work for signed variables,

```
int x;
int tmp;

if (x < 0) {

   tmp = -x;
   tmp = tmp << 1;
   x = -tmp;
}
else {

   x = x << 1;
}
```

Comment: Generally, if you're dealing with signed variables, you want to be well aware of what are you doing precisely, and generally should avoid bit manipulations. 
If I had to multiply using shifts, I'd probably keep the sign bit as a separate char and make sure to put it back in. Or write it in pure assembly and abuse the carry flag.

Comment: Usually -ve numbers are stored 2s compliment in which case shifting should work fine and preserve the sign bit. You still have problems with overflow, but that is the case with straight multiplication also.

Answer (score 0):

Just to make sure we are all clear, to do this as everyone has suggested, bitwise shift left (<<)

Every time you shift left, you are multiplying by a factor of two essentially.

```
int x;
int result;
x = 5;

// result = 10 (multiply by a factor of 2 or 2^1=2)
result = 5<<1;

//result = 20 (multiply by a factor of 4 or 2^2=4)
result = 5<<2;

//result = 40 (multiply by a factor of 8 or 2^3=8)
result = 5<<3;
```